# Interface describes a method that is always implemented as async. How to always get compiler warnings when await keyword is omitted?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dependency-injection, async-await, resharper

Trying to keep the wheels on while we introduce async to a legacy application.  I want to give other team members solid coding practices so we minimize trouble.

As we convert methods to be async **they often also still need to be consumed by syncronous code** that we lack time to refactor.  We have resolved to use Task.Run() for this rather than maintain separate async and sync versions of the method.

**CS1404 is a valuable warning to us** because we have had bugs when accidentally running async methods without the await keyword.

The problem is that when the async method implements an interface, **we don't always get CS1404 when calling from syncronous code**.  We have the same problem with Resharper's version of the warning.

Consider this interface:

```
public interface IDefineAMethod
{
    Task<bool> MyMethod();
}
```

And a class that implements the method using the async keyword...

```
public class ImplementsMethodAsync : IDefineAMethod
{
    public async Task<bool> MyMethod()
    {
        // Real awaitable work normally goes here...
        await Task.Yield();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now a class that runs that method in a syncronous context in two ways:  One against an instance of the interface and one against a class instance...

```
public class RunsAsyncMethodsSynchronously
{
    public bool RunsAsyncMethod(IDefineAMethod myObject)
    {
        myObject.MyMethod();

        return false;
    }

    public bool AlsoRunsAsyncMethod()
    {
        var myObject = new ImplementsMethodAsync();
        myObject.MyMethod();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Paste all that into Visual Studio and you will get a warning on the second call to MyMethod(), but not the first.

**The interface doesn't explicitly say the method is async so this makes sense.**

But what do we do now?

For us it would be ideal if we could specify async right in the interface but this isn't allowed.

We could rename MyMethod => MyMethodAsync in the hopes that devs and reviewers would notice the lack of await keywords but appending "Async" to the name of everything is a drag when the long run goal is that everything will be async someday.  Its like appending "IAmWritingGoodCodeHere" to every method name.

Any ideas how to manage this?

To complete my example, here is the Async version of the last class.  If you paste that into VS you will see both methods give us the CS4014 error **so its only the situation where we are reusing async methods in a syncronous context that causes trouble.**

```
public class RunsAsyncMethodsAsynchronously
{
    public async Task<bool> RunsAsyncMethod(IDefineAMethod myObject)
    {
        myObject.MyMethod();

        return false;
    }

    public async Task<bool> AlsoRunsAsyncMethod()
    {
        var myObject = new ImplementsMethodAsync();
        myObject.MyMethod();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I never used it, but you could take a look at [Lindhart.Analyser.MissingAwaitWarning](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lindhart.Analyser.MissingAwaitWarning/). In your specific example, I'm wondering why the task returns a `bool` which is never used.

Comment: Thanks Ill look.   The bool stuff is just an artifact of me trying to boil down some real world code for an example. Its not relevant

Answer (score 4):

> We have resolved to use Task.Run() for this rather than maintain separate async and sync versions of the method.

I recommend using the [flag argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development#the-flag-argument-hack). This allows you to have both `MyMethod` and `MyMethodAsync` without duplicating (too much) logic.

> The problem is that when the async method implements an interface, we don't always get CS1404 when calling from syncronous code. We have the same problem with Resharper's version of the warning.

I have also observed this, but I haven't tracked down exactly why it's happening.

> For us it would be ideal if we could specify async right in the interface but this isn't allowed.

`async` is an implementation detail. Really, the warning *should* trigger regardless of where the method is defined. But I'm not up-to-speed on the pros and cons (often there are very obscure reasons why the compiler team *doesn't* put in warnings like this).

> appending "Async" to the name of everything is a drag when the long run goal is that everything will be async someday. Its like appending "IAmWritingGoodCodeHere" to every method name.

The `Async` suffix is the [common naming pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) since the very beginning of `async`, over a decade ago. It persists, with very few exceptions, and remains a useful convention. I'd prefer to think of it less as "useless once everything is `async`" (which doesn't actually happen; synchronous methods should stay synchronous), and more as "our code is now more like all the other `async` code in the world", which is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  Ive enjoyed your Cookbook btw.